# Cumulative sum of counts is not working for distinct values of users

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

Table "*users*":

| id | name | email | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | FSDSD2 | FSDSD2@thebluedot.co | 2022-05-29 14:19:21 |
| 47 | Fxz3 | Fxz3@gmail.com | 2022-05-30 20:12:15 |
| 48 | Fgh3 | Fgh3@gmail.com | 2022-05-31 20:12:15 |
| 49 | Fghxc3 | Fghxc3@gmail.com | 2022-06-01 20:12:15 |
| 50 | Fdx3 | Fdx3@gmail.com | 2022-06-02 20:12:15 |
| 51 | Fg3q3 | Fg3q3@gmail.com | 2022-06-03 20:12:15 |
| 88 | Fbhgt | Fbhgt@gmail.co | 2022-05-23 16:38:41 |
| 112 | Fht | Fht@gmail.com | 2022-05-24 16:19:23 |
| 113 | Y14gss | Y14gss@gmail.com | 2022-05-25 16:42:44 |
| 114 | sfhf | sfhf@gmail.com | 2022-05-26 12:10:40 |
| 115 | A2czu | A2czu@thebluedot.co | 2022-05-27 14:00:31 |
| 116 | Cc1sn | Cc1sn@gmail.com | 2022-05-28 12:04:56 |

Table "*oxygen_point_earns*":

| id | user_id | oxygen_point | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 116 | 50.00 | 2022-05-23 17:49:30 |
| 3 | 113 | 10.00 | 2022-05-24 07:49:46 |
| 4 | 114 | 10.00 | 2022-05-25 07:50:42 |
| 5 | 46 | 50.00 | 2022-05-26 07:55:19 |
| 6 | 47 | 40.00 | 2022-05-27 13:28:17 |
| 7 | 48 | 30.00 | 2022-05-28 13:32:19 |
| 8 | 49 | 10.00 | 2022-05-29 13:32:19 |
| 9 | 50 | 5.00 | 2022-05-30 13:32:19 |
| 10 | 51 | 10.00 | 2022-05-31 13:32:19 |
| 11 | 88 | 20.00 | 2022-06-01 13:32:19 |
| 12 | 112 | 50.00 | 2022-06-02 13:32:19 |
| 13 | 115 | 10.00 | 2022-06-03 13:32:19 |
| 14 | 112 | 20.00 | 2022-06-03 16:32:19 |

I have two tables:

- "*users*", which stores users basic information
- "*oxygen_point_earns*", which stores oxygen points earned by specific users

The "*users*" table has 12 rows, though the "*oxygen_point_earns*" table contains 13 records, which means that one user can win points even more than once.

I was trying to made some calculation between those tables (e.g. dividing the total of weekly gained points by the weekly users cumulative sum, for each user). The problem occurs when I attempt to get the users cumulative sum.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(op.created_at), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') AS week,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(ORDER BY MIN(op.created_at)) AS user_count,
       SUM(op.oxygen_point)                            AS op_weekly
FROM      users us
LEFT JOIN oxygen_point_earns op 
       ON us.id = op.user_id
GROUP  BY week
ORDER  BY week
```

This query gets me the following output:

[image: enter description here]

As you can see, even though the points are correctly computed, the total user count is wrong at the second row: it should be 12 instead of 13 (First week I got **6** users then next week 6 more users registered. So my total user count is 12. On second row I should get 12.)

I tried **DISTINCT**, **GROUP_CONCAT** but didn't work. How can I fix this query to get true result of users counts?

Comment: Can you share samples for the input table "*oxygen_point_earns*"?

Comment: I upload example tables as a csv.

Comment: user 115 registered on '2022-05-27' but earned points for the first time on '2022-06-03'. On which week will he be counted?

Comment: 2022-05-27, I mean point earning dates are not important because user 115 can gain another point also at 2022-06-02 or in same day also.

Comment: How is it possible for user 46 to register on '2022-05-29' and earn points 3 days earlier on '2022-05-26'?

Comment: its just a sample data sorry about that.

Comment: Then post correct sample data and expected results so that we can test the code.

Comment: Update your post with the answer you removed, so that it may provide help to other people find what you need. @Canİlgu

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward option is to separate the two operations (aggregation and windowing) using a subquery/cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(op.created_at), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') AS week,
           COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)                                            AS cnt,
           SUM(op.oxygen_point)                                               AS op_weekly
    FROM      users us
    LEFT JOIN oxygen_point_earns op ON us.id = op.user_id
    GROUP  BY week
)
SELECT week,
       SUM(cnt) OVER(ORDER BY week)  AS user_count,
       op_weekly
FROM cte
ORDER BY week
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The answer is correct for me.

Comment: @Canİlgu this will count a user for every week that he earns points and not only the week he registered. Is this what you want?

Comment: @forpas I tested query and is working fine for my local database. But I tried at production database and gives wrong user count.. Like you said its count for every week that he earns points.. But it should count only the week he registered.. Do you have any idea to fix that?

Comment: @Canİlgu I already asked correct sample data and expected results so that I can test a solution.

Comment: I'd ask, would you count just the first week a user earns points or only the week he registered? And in the first case, if it's the required one, is it plausible for a user not to earn points in the week he registered? @CanIlgu

Comment: Users can earn points any time. independently of oxygen_point_earns we could get weekly registered users from users table. @lemon solution works well for my local database. User count and points calculated well. But when I test it on other dbs result is; user count is bigger than count of users table.

Comment: In that case, it's a completely different problem with respect to the one presented here, as you would work just with the users table and it wouldn't involve oxygen points. For more troubleshooting, forpas told you exactly what is needed here. There's no way we can know a-priori what specifically is not working.